# How do I update other Ubuntu partitions without rebooting into them?

Tags: apt, chroot

I have a number of Ubuntu partitions on my computer. This allows me to run previous, current and development versions concurrently.

I'd quite like to install updates to the other partitions, without actually booting into them. So I'd like to be able to run `sudo aptitude update` followed by `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`.

How do I do this?

Comment: Are they all the same architecture? What about just `chroot`ing it?

Comment: @izx yep they are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of techniques, the simplest is to use a chrooted environment. In this environment you can then run `sudo aptitude update` and most other command line tools.

Alternatively you could create a number of virtual box virtual machines that used the partitions as their hard drives - I have not tried this.

For the chroot environment
mount each partition in a directory for example:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/partition_penguin
sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt/partition_penguin
```

Bind in the system directories to give access to the hardware:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/partition_penguin/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/partition_penguin/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/partition_penguin/sys
```

And then enter the chroot environment and run your commands:

```
sudo chroot /mnt/partition_penguin /bin/bash
sudo aptitude update
```

Comment: I get a few errors: `sudo: unable to resolve host greg-precise` and `E: Could not open lock file /var/lock/aptitude - open (2: No such file or directory)` but it seems to have worked.

Comment: If you plan on doing this regularly, also look at `schroot` to automate some of the above steps.