# Perform upgrades on another ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, 12.10, xbmc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update other Ubuntu partitions without rebooting into them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146923/how-do-i-update-other-ubuntu-partitions-without-rebooting-into-them)

So I run XBMCBuntu on my primary partition, and have 12.10 on my secondary partition, which I do most of my work in. Is there a way, either thru terminal or otherwise, to do apt-updates and upgrades to the XBMC partition without logging out of 12.10 and into XBMC?

Comment: Just as something to consider... I run XBMC to the tv upstairs while i have my desktop running in the basement. It's a little bit of work to get it setup, but it makes for easier system maintenance and no rebooting to use either system. Take a look here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX